# Best practice for website with multi language dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multilingual

I'm developing MVC site and I'm trying to understand best way to store and use dynamic content, e.g. News articles, blog posts etc., in multiple languages.

Currently I have the model having both language properties and I switch the output language depending on selected language and culture with simple `switch/case`.

Is my approach sufficient enough, or is there a better practice of doing this with MVC and Entity Framework?

Currently I have following model

```
public class NewsArticle
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }

    public EntityStatus Status  { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string Title_English { get; set; }
    public string Title_Spanish { get; set; }

    public string PromoSample_English { get; set; }
    public string PromoSample_Spanish { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body_English { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body_Spanish { get; set; }
}
```

**Let me know if I need to ask this question elsewhere.**

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using resource files, you have one resx file for each language:

```
Mui.resx default
Mui.es.resx
Mui.fr.resx 
etc.
```

and use it in the views and controllers by calling

```
Mui.Key
```

e.g. `Mui.HomePageTitle`

you can this in a demo working live here: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com/
see the language dropdown in the top right corner

Comment: Hi and thank you for answer. I'm sorry that I didn't mention in OP, updated the title, but I need something for dynamic content. I use `rex` to have language specific words in applications, e.g. forms, modals, etc.. I'm looking for something where the actual content, e.g. news article, blog post, is in two different languages.

Comment: well, if you're not showing both languages at the same time, I don't see the point of having a model with properties for 2 languages, plus it's not flexible approach, imagine that you want to add another language, maybe have different tables (same as different resx), and pull from the specific table depending on current language

Comment: Something like adding language enum property and then just create two separate records indicating the language?

Comment: that could work too, using enum or maybe the current culture/convention, thats up to you